# Switch Wordpress Post Template based on URL query Parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

I have a wordpress magazine website. I want to combine Endless Scrolling & Pagination for the Article Page.
**Question:** Is it possible to show the same post(Article) different ways (Paginated, Endless Scrolling), based on the query param of the visit ?
 Like for example ***(If "?layout=paginated" then the post should be "paginated", else "Turn On the Endless Scrolling")***.

Is there any plugin or custom code to do that ? 

A real example like this used by nickiswift.com:

https://www.nickiswift.com/137343/movie-villains-who-are-gorgeous-in-real-life/

https://www.nickiswift.com/137343/movie-villains-who-are-gorgeous-in-real-life/?utm_source=zergnet.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=zergnet_3987140&utm_content=5

Tried a bunch of plugins but no results...

Answer (score 0):

In your child-theme template you could simply use a `If` statement to run the endless scrolling or not.

For example if your script runs on a specific class `.endless`

```
<?php 
    if ($_GET['layout' == 'paginated') {$class=''}
    else {$class='endless'};   
?>
```

Then to the container you want to be endless or paginated

```
<div class="container <?php echo $class; ?>">
```

Of course this code must be customised to your particular case.